# Few page titles suffixed(appended) by a keyword

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a strange problem. Few page titles are suffixed(appended) by a specific keyword called "Salwar Kameez". When i open the page the page title in the browser doesn't have the appended keyword. I am not sure where it is coming from. Default html head is empty in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It might be anything. Do this fro your root folder

```
find . | xargs grep 'Salwar Kamee' -sl
```

and see in which file is the string present. Once you know that you will be able to debug the code.

Comment: i did and i found the keyword in fpc cache and couple of other files. 158EF63AB0A6BF4196E54424C20E7865F684829_PAGE
./var/cache/fpc--2/fpc--2c/fpc--2c1/fpc--2c1f/fpc--2c1f0/fpc--2c1f0b/fpc---bc5_77B674426CAF71DE9565B87AB8C5F1D3B7154518_PAGE
./var/cache/fpc--2/fpc--2c/fpc--2cb/fpc--2cb7/fpc--2cb70/fpc--2cb70b/fpc---bc5_1EB0B8EF736F694597F6C5569289D27F7105973C_PAGE
./var/cache/mage--8/mage---bc5_CONFIG_GLOBAL_STORES_ADMIN
./var/cache/mage--6/mage---bc5_CONFIG_GLOBAL_WEBSITES
./var/cache/mage--f/mage---bc5_CEF784AE2E7E03DECDEE6BD991ED24372E33086F

Comment: No files outside cache folders?

Comment: Nope. Not at all.

Comment: Flush all the caches and search again. If the files persist, delete them manually and see if it reproduces.

Comment: also try the search just as `find . | xargs grep 'Salwar' -sl`